# Can't install yahoo messenger on windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, installation, yahoo-messenger

I am trying to install Yahoo Messenger 10 on windows xp but it never finish. It create a GLBD6.tmp and it use 100% CPU. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

To the obvious question of what to do about it.  I got a different error trying to install Yahoo instant messenger v10 on one of my computers. I tried one suggested thing, reinstalling the windows installer was what was suggested for the error I got, but no luck.

I tried an earlier version, was fine.

If you're willing to then you could try v9 or earlier,  it's available on filehippo.com

http://www.filehippo.com/download_yahoo_messenger/

maybe in the near future there'll be a new version of v10 or there'll be v11, that'll work for you

Answer (score 0):

Clean out your temp files, reboot, download the installer again, and try again.

The temp folders in question are located at:

- %temp%
- C:\windows\temp

Answer (score 0):

Check you havent run out of disk space.

Run http://live.sysinternals.com/Tools/Procmon.exe and watch the installer run.  Look for the last FAILURE before it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had problems installing Yahoo Messenger. I kept getting an error message basically saying that my firewall was preventing the installation. My windows firewall was 'turned off' as I normally use Zone Alarm. I turned off Zone Alarm as suggested by someone on YouTube...to no avail.

I finally solved this problem by Reactivating Windows Firewall thereby enabling me to add the YM startup to the 'Allowed' program list. (The list knew that it was Yahoo messenger even though the installation exe had a different name)...problem solved. Installed without a hiccup.